# Update query showing exception

Tags: database, jsp, sql-update, prepared-statement

BOX_ID column is integer rest are varchar

```
sql="UPDATE TOYS SET ?=?,?=?,?=? WHERE NAME=? AND LICENSE=? AND BOX_ID=? ";
p_statement2=connection.prepareStatement(sql);
p_statement2.setString(1, "NAME");
p_statement2.setString(2, "toy1");
p_statement2.setString(3, "VENDOR");
p_statement2.setString(4, "vendor1");
p_statement2.setString(5, "SIZE");
p_statement2.setString(6, "size1");
p_statement2.setString(7, "toyx");
p_statement2.setString(8, "license1");
p_statement2.setInt(9, 11);
try
{
p_statement2.executeUpdate();
}
catch(Exception kl)
{
kl.toString();
kl.printStackTrace();
p_statement2.close();
}
```

getting the following exception-

> java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification

Comment: You can't bind identifiers. So it says

Answer (score 1):

It is expected. When you bind parameter using setString method, parameter value will be escaped and put in single/double quotes. In this case, your column name will also be put in single/double quotes and your database will throw error in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Why did you set column names like `?`? You can't do this. Try something like:

```
sql="UPDATE TOYS SET Name=?, Vendor=?, Size=? WHERE NAME=? AND LICENSE=? AND BOX_ID=? ";
p_statement2=connection.prepareStatement(sql);
p_statement2.setString(1, "toy1");
p_statement2.setString(2, "vendor1");
p_statement2.setString(3, "size1");
p_statement2.setString(4, "toyx");
p_statement2.setString(5, "license1");
p_statement2.setInt(6, 11);
try
{
   p_statement2.executeUpdate();
}
catch(Exception kl)
{
   kl.toString();
   kl.printStackTrace();
   p_statement2.close();
}
```

Comment: i need to do this because at back end DB table column counts & even column names can also be changed..as it is required

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
//assign values dynamically   
String col1 = "NAME";
    String col2 = "VENDOR";
    String col3 = "SIZE";    

//create sql
    sql="UPDATE TOYS SET "+col1+"=?,"+col2+"=?,"+col3+"=? WHERE NAME=? AND LICENSE=? AND BOX_ID=? ";
        p_statement2=connection.prepareStatement(sql);
        p_statement2.setString(1, "toy1");
        p_statement2.setString(2, "vendor1");
        p_statement2.setString(3, "size1");
        p_statement2.setString(4, "toyx");
        p_statement2.setString(5, "license1");
        p_statement2.setInt(6, 11);
        try
        {
        p_statement2.executeUpdate();
        }
        catch(Exception kl)
        {
        kl.toString();
        kl.printStackTrace();
        p_statement2.close();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

finally , it's done.
i first made sql string under loop by getting column names by rsmd.getColumnName() method and also appended "=" operator and comma oprator as required. Then passed it to preparedstatement creating code and got it done.
thanks all for your support.